# Install extensions after building VSCode from source

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have built vscode from source because I want to work on adding a new feature to it. Unfortunately, I can't seem to be able to install extensions. I built a .deb package using the gulp task, and installed it

[image: Here's what I see when I try to type 'Extensions' in the command palette]

It's missing the 'Install Extension' menu and a few others.

The version I am running as of right now: Code - OSS - Version 
Version 1.2.1 - Commit fe7f407b95b7f78405846188259504b34ef72761

Is there anything else I have to build / install to be able to install extensions from inside the editor ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found it. Looking at https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/1557 I tried to edit product.json and added the following to enable extensions:

```
"extensionsGallery": {
    "serviceUrl": "https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/_apis/public/gallery",
    "cacheUrl": "https://vscode.blob.core.windows.net/gallery/index",
    "itemUrl": "https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items"
}
```

This effectively enables installing extensions from vscode's marketplace